# Create QR code with Numeric encoding type

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I have long int number and I want to encode it to QRCode with exactly numeric type of encoding. Now I use CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator"), but in this case I don't know how to choose type of encoding. Is there a way to create QR code with chosen type of encoding?

Comment: please check this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944184/swift-generate-a-qrcode/48945637#48945637

Answer (score 0):

[The Apple documentation for CIQRCodeGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator) indicates that you should use `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` (Objective-C) or `String.Encoding.isoLatin1` (Swift) for encoding QR codes.

Here is a quick example for generating a UIImage from a given input integer in Swift 4.

```
enum QRInputEncoding: Int {
    case octal = 8
    case decimal = 10
    case hexadecimal = 16
}

func makeQRImage(input: Int, encoding: QRInputEncoding) -> UIImage? {
    let encoded = String(input, radix: encoding.rawValue)
    print(encoded)
    guard let data = encoded.data(using: .isoLatin1) else {
        return nil
    }
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator", withInputParameters: ["inputMessage": data])
    return filter?.outputImage.map(UIImage.init(ciImage:))
}

makeQRImage(input: 100000, encoding: .octal) // prints 303240
makeQRImage(input: 100000, encoding: .decimal) // prints 100000
makeQRImage(input: 100000, encoding: .hexadecimal) // prints 186a0
```

This allows you to change the generated QR code output so that readers can read less characters in, resulting in a smaller QR code for the same number.

Comment: Now I do the same. But I am not sure what type of encoding use in this case, numeric or alphabetic or 8-bit.

Comment: I have edited my answer to allow customising the output encoding of the number passed in for your QR code. The previous example only output decimal numbers, now base 8 and 16 are options as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate QRCode image and return

```
func makeQRImage(inputText: String) -> UIImage {  

            let data = inputText.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")

            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            filter.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

       return filter.outputImage
}
```

Anything else you can follow this code: https://github.com/appcoda/QR-Code-Generator

Also the tutorial : https://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-generator-tutorial